# WinForms UI sometimes non-responsive

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, task-parallel-library

I'm updating on a WinForms application that talks to a GSM modem and in a nutshell, performs the following functionality:

- accepts incoming SMS messages and uploads them to a SOAP-based web service
- downloads messages from a SOAP-based web service, converts them to SMS messages and sends them to destination addresses

This functionality is divided as such:

1. The code that handles incoming SMS messages is part of a GSM library.  It's set up as an event handler that fires when the modem receives a new incoming messages.  The event handler just converts the message into a specific string format (source phone number,message body) and adds it to a queue for uploading to the web service.
2. The code that uploads the messages to the web service runs as a task which is started by a timer with a 15 second interval.  This code simply dequeues all of the SMS messages, uploads them to the web service, updates a label in the UI to indicate that there are no messages left in the queue and then terminates.
3. The code that downloads messages from the web service also runs as a task and it, too, is triggered by a timer with a 15 second interval.  It simply downloads any new messages from the web service, adds them to a fixed-size "outgoing" queue, updates a label in the UI to indicate the number of messages in the queue and then terminates.
4. Finally, the code that constructs and sends the outgoing SMS messages from the queue runs as a task.  This code runs in a fairly tight loop that sends messages constantly when there are any in the outgoing queue.  This code also updates a label in the UI after it removes a message from the queue and sends it on to the destination phone number.

To re-cap, items 2, 3 and 4 above run as tasks.  I pass the same cancellation token into each task so I can cancel them if the user shuts down my application.  Everything seems to be working as expected except in the following scenario: if the GSM modem is running but my application is not, incoming SMS messages will get stored on the SIM card until it's full (30 messages in this case) and after that, they will begin getting queued up at the SMSC.  When my application is started, I check for messages stored on the SIM and process them.  If the SIM is full, as soon as I begin processing and deleting those messages, any messages queued at the SMSC will start to be delivered.  It's at this point that sometimes my UI will freeze.  I essentially have three pieces of code that make UI updates and they're called by the various tasks I described above:

```
    // update the status textbox (a multi-line textbox)
    private void UpdateStatusText(string text)
    {
        textBoxStatus.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { textBoxStatus.AppendText(text + Environment.NewLine); });
    }

    // update UI with the current number of messages in the incoming queue
    private void UpdateIncomingMessageQueueCount()
    {
        labelIncomingQueueCounter.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { labelIncomingQueueCounter.Text = messagesFromDevicesQueue.GetCount().ToString(); });
    }

    // update the UI with the current number of messages in the outgoing queue
    private void UpdateOutgoingMessageQueueCount()
    {
        labelOutgoingQueueCounter.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { labelOutgoingQueueCounter.Text = messagesToDevicesQueue.GetCount().ToString(); });
    }
```

I'm not entirely sure what's causing the freezing to happen but when it occurs and I'm able to break within the debugger, I can see some tasks that have a status of "Blocked" and the hover over tip says "No waiting information is available".  As I said earlier, this only seems to happen when there are a lot of incoming messages.  In that case, I'm calling UpdateIncomingMessageQueueCount() a fair amount (after each incoming message is enqueued).  In the case of UpdateIncomingMessageQueueCount(), it gets the number of messages in the queue via the queues .GetCount() method.  The fixed-size queue object is implemented like this:

```
public class FixedSizeQueue<T>
{

private readonly List<T> queue = new List<T>();
private readonly object syncObj = new object();

public int Size { get; private set; }

public FixedSizeQueue(int size)
{
    Size = size;
}

public void Enqueue(T obj)
{
    lock (syncObj)
    {
        queue.Insert(0, obj);

        if (queue.Count > Size)
        {
            queue.RemoveRange(Size, queue.Count - Size);
        }
    }
}

public T[] DequeueAllItems()
{
    lock (syncObj)
    {
        var result = queue.ToArray();
        queue.Clear();
        return result;
    }
}

public void RemoveFirstItem()
{
    lock (syncObj)
    {
        if (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            queue.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }
}

public T Peek()
{
    lock (syncObj)
    {
        if (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            var result = queue[0];
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
}

public void Flush()
{
    lock (syncObj)
    {
        queue.Clear();
    }
}

public int GetCount()
{
    lock (syncObj)
    {
        return queue.Count;
    }
}
}
```

Since I'm using .BeginInvoke() to update the UI, I'm wondering if my performance issue is related to lots of asynchronous attempts to call .GetCount() on the queue object?  The UI will eventually become responsive again but this obviously shouldn't be happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `BeginInvoke` for every message that comes in. That ends up queue-ing a whole bunch of UI updates that happen one after another, effectively blocking the UI thread.

You'd be better off calling `Invoke` for each message. Or, even better, changing your design so that you empty the queue and do a single UI update with all of the messages in one shot.